# Lenses: Composing backwards and (.) in Lens context

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have been reading [this article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) and in one of their section it is stated:

> Lenses compose backwards. Can't we make `(.)` behave like functions?
>
> You're right, we could. We don't for various reasons, but the
>   intuition is right. Lenses should combine just like functions. One
>   thing that's important about that is id can either pre- or post-
>   compose with any lens without affecting it.

What does that mean by Lenses compose backwards ?

Also, what does this mean: Can't we make `(.)` behave like functions ?

`(.)` is a function and by using it with Lens does it make `(.)` to behave like something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could think of the `Getter` part of a lens as a function, which you can extract using `view`. For example, the lens way of writing the `fst` function is:

```
view _1 :: (a,b) -> a
```

Now observe:

```
view _1 . view _2 :: (c, (a,b)) -> a  -- First take the second pair element, then the first 
view (_1 . _2)    :: ((b,a) ,c) -> a   -- This is "backwards" (exactly the opposite order of the above)
```

For lenses, `(.)` doesn't behave like it would for functions. For functions, `f . g` means "first apply g, then f", but for lenses, it means `first use the lens f, then use the lens g`. Actually, the `(.)` function is the same for both types, but lens' types make it seem like it's backwards.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t%3aLens) type:

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

For our illustrative purposes, we can stick to the less general simple lens type, [`Lens'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t%3aLens-39-). The right side then becomes:

```
forall f. Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

Intuitively, `(a -> f a)` is an operation on a part of a structure of type `s`, which is promoted to an operation on the whole structure, `(s -> f s)`. (The functor type constructor `f` is part of the trickery which allows lenses to generalize getters, setters and lots of other things. We do not need to worry about it for now.) In other words:

- From the user point of view, a lens allows to, given a whole, focus on a part of it.
- Implementation-wise, a lens is a function which takes a function of the part and results in a function of the whole.

(Note how, in the descriptions I just made, "part" and "whole" appear in different orders.)

Now, a lens is a function, and functions can be composed. As we know, `(.)` has type:

```
(.) :: (y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> (x -> z)
```

Let us make the involved types simple lenses (For the sake of clarity, I will drop the constraint and the `forall`). `x` becomes `a -> f a`, `y` becomes `s -> f s` and `z` becomes `t -> f t`. The specialized type of `(.)` would then be:

```
((s -> f s) -> t -> f t) -> ((a -> f a) -> s -> f s) -> ((a -> f a) -> t -> f t)
```

The lens we get as result has type `(a -> f a) -> (t -> f t)`. So, a composed lens `firstLens . secondLens` takes an operation on the part focused by `secondLens` and makes it an operation on the whole structure `firstLens` aims at. That just happens to match the order in which OO-style field references are composed, which is opposite to the order in which vanilla Haskell record accessors are composed.