# How can the type of a composite Traversal be worked out?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm following [a blog post on lens' traversals](https://blog.jakuba.net/2014/08/06/lens-tutorial-stab-traversal-part-2.html). In it, there is a composition of

```
traverse.posts
```

and it ends up with type

```
(Traversable t, Applicative f) => 
   ([Post] -> f [Post]) -> t User -> f (t User)
```

I understand that it is function composition., but I'm a bit confused on how it ends up with that type.

Can anyone help me to walk through this?

Comment: Related: [*Lenses: Composing backwards and (.) in Lens context*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23092468/2751851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the following types for the functions:

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
posts :: Functor f => ([Post] -> f [Post]) -> User -> f User
```

Let's line up the types for `traverse` and `posts` (in that order) so we can see what's going on (I'll omit the type-class constraints for this), and let's add the implied parentheses around the results of the functions (`a -> b -> c` is a shortcut for `a -> (b -> c)`)

```
                        (a    ->   f b   ) -> (t a -> f (t b))
([Post] -> f [Post]) -> (User ->   f User)
```

From this we can see that `a ~ User`, `b ~ User` (`~` here means 'is identified with', or 'is equal to'), so let's specialize traverse and write down the types of the functions again:

```
                        (User ->   f User) -> (t User -> f (t User))
([Post] -> f [Post]) -> (User ->   f User)
```

From this we can see that the composition will have the type (omitting the constraints for now, again)

```
([Post] -> f [Post]) ->                       (t User -> f (t User))
```

Or without the optional parentheses

```
([Post] -> f [Post]) -> t User -> f (t User)
```

Now what about the constraints? Well the use of `posts` gives us the `Functor f` constraint, and `traverse` gives us `Applicative f` and `Traversable t`, but because `Applicative` is a sub-class of `Functor` (it's defined as `class Functor f => Applicative f where -- ...`), we don't have to specify the `Functor f` constraint, it's already there.

So we are left with:

```
traverse . posts :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => 
                    ([Post] -> f [Post]) -> t User -> f (t User)
```